# How can I pass parameters from a struct to a function correctly?

Tags: c++, function, struct

I would like the function dateCreate to pass the given parameters to the ones from the struct.

I have tried by having the Date d variable as a function parameter but it still shows me the error "field "day/month/year" could not be resolved".

```
struct Date{
int day;
int month;
int year;
} ;

Date dateCreate (int d, int m, int y){
 Date d;
 d.day =d;
 d.month = m;
 d.year =y;
return 0;
};


int main() {
 int d,m,y;
 cin << d << m << y;
 cout << dateCreate(d,m,y); //Not completely sure if this is right either.


return 0;
}
```

I want the function to create a Date type of data from the integers given. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`dateCreate` should return `d`, not `0`.

For expression `cout << dateCreate(d,m,y)` to compile you need to implement `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Date const&)`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a free function, I'd suggest you give your `struct` a constructor

```
struct Date{
    Date(int _day, int _month, int _year)
    : day(_day), month(_month), year(_year)
    { }

    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
```

Then you can create this object like

```
int d,m,y;
cin >> d >> m >> y;
Date date(d, m, y);
```

To do something like

```
cout << date;
```

you'd need to [overload `operator<<` for your `Date` struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719)

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent code:

```
struct Date
{
    int d;
    int m;
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    int d = 1, m = 1, y = 1980;
    std::cin >> d >> m >> y;
    Date date{d, m, y}; // default constructor is called here
}
```

This said, because the problem you are solving is reading a date, you should probably implement it like this:

```
struct Date
{
    int d;
    int m;
    int y;
};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, Date& d)
{
    int d = 1, m = 1, y = 1980;

    if(in >> d >> m >> y) // only set values if they were read successfully
        d = Date{d, m, y};

    return in;
}
```

Client code:

```
int main()
{
    Date d{1, 1, 1980};
    in >> d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way to fix your snippet is providing an output operator for `Date` objects, e.g.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Date& date)
{
   return os << date.day << "/" << date.month << "/" << date.year;
}
```

then using the correct operators to read the user input

```
cin >> d >> m >> y;
```

and finally using the `Date` constructor generated by the compiler:

```
cout << Date{d, m, y};
```

You don't need a function creating a date object as long as you don't verify the input.

Note, however, that `Date` objects can now be in invalid states (negative day or month values etc.), so for future refinement, you should either implement a proper constructor that throws upon illegal input, or change the `createDate` function such that it e.g. returns a `std::optional<Date>` which is empty (`std::nullopt`) upon illegal input.